# What is the keyword "this" in "this.state" referring to in the React.js code below?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and have been learning it for the past few months now.
Early on I learned that I had to know the ES6 syntax in order to master it very well.
So I got into it and learn about the keyword "this" in various context.
However, I cannot tell what the keyword "this" is referring to in "this.state" in the code below.
Is it pointing to the Car class?
Thanks

```js
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: "red"};
  }
  render() {
    return <h2>I have a {this.state.color} Car!</h2>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a constructor function, `this` is the **instance** being created from the class.

Comment: What is exactly being created from the Car class?

Comment: @Leealp "the instance being created from the class". An instance of the Car class is being created.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {color: "red"};
  }
  render() {
    return <h2>I have a {this.state.color} Car!</h2>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Car />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

with the *this* keyword, it can be useful to look at what is being encapsulated. You are within your constructor, which is within your class Car, therefor this refers to the Car object being created when using this component.